# Why doesn't Outlook 2007 return the same results as Windows 7 search?

Tags: search, windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

When I attempt to search for an email, if I search for the email using the search toolbar within Outlook 2007, no results are found.

However, if I use the Windows 7 built-in search functionality found when you click the Start button, using the same search criteria as I did in Outlook, Windows 7 finds the email immediately.

**Question**: how can I make Outlook 2007 find the email(s) I'm searching for that Windows 7 finds that Outlook doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Outlook 2007, but on Outlook 2010 if you go to File - Options - Search, you can modify the results to include from All folders instead of Current Folder which is default for 2010.  You may want to see if there such an option for Outlook 2007.  Good Luck!!

Comment: 2007 is the same